# Problema con redirección .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

Tengo el siguiente .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php

RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)$ category.php?slug=$1 

RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)$ game.php?slug=$1
```

El problema está en que tanto los enlaces que van a category.php y game.php pasan por category.php. Es decir, la primera regla funciona correctamente, llevándome a la categoría correspondiente, pero la segunda regla no funciona, me lleva a category.php. No sé como hacer que se diferencien estas dos reglas.

Comment: ¿Cómo diferenciar entre categoría y juego si la expresión es la misma?

Comment: ¿Te refieres a que una sea `RewriteRule ^categoria/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)$ category.php?slug=$1` y la otra  `RewriteRule ^juego/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)$ game.php?slug=$1`? Mi idea es que vaya directamente a la raíz, sin que haya algo en medio como sitio.com/categoria/avion, sino directamente sitio.com/avion y lo mismo con el nombre del juego.

Comment: Ahora mismo está yendo todo a category.php, antes de crear esa RewriteRule iba todo a game.php, si pongo game arriba va a game por ejemplo. Pero como digo, mi intención es poder mostrar en la raíz sin tener que colocar nada antes.

Comment: Corrijo la pregunta: Si tuvieras sitio.com/abc1 ¿cuál archivo php debería ejecutarse? Según tu lógica.

Comment: Ni idea, en este momento es imposible que sepa a donde debe ir. Lo que no sé es decirle a cada uno por donde tiene que ir.

Comment: Pues precisamente el procesador de reglas tampoco tiene idea, y por eso siempre todo lo manda a category, que es la última regla que cumple.

Comment: He buscado un montón en diversos sitios y no sé como tengo que hacerlo. De hecho llevo todo el día con este asunto.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya lo he solucionado. Lo que he hecho ha sido poner parte de la URL que quería mostrar como prefijo:

```
RewriteRule ^juegos-de-([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)/?$ category.php?slug=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)$ game.php?slug=$1
```

De esta manera no hay un prefijo seguido de "/" sino de "-" por lo que parece que es directamente una URL que depende de root.